# Change thread pool size in Jetty 9

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

How can I change thread pool size in embedded Jetty 9? Do we need any specific component for this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From [docs](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-config-what.html):

> The Server instance provides a ThreadPool instance that is the default
>   Executor service other Jetty server components use. The prime
>   configuration of the thread pool is the maximum and minimum size and
>   is set in etc/jetty.xml.

```
<Configure id="server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">   
<Set name="threadPool">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
      <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
      <Set name="maxThreads">1000</Set>
    </New>
</Set> 
</Configure>
```

Or

```
QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool(100, 10);
Server server = new Server(threadPool);
```

Comment: Your code sample doesn't work for Jetty 9.04, as there are no setThreadPool method in Server class. Also, I need such preference for embedded jetty server, I've updated a question.

Comment: ThreadPool can be passed in on the constructor of the Server instance, or just call server.getThreadPool() and tweak that before calling .start()

Comment: In Jetty-9 many of the method signatures have changed for server. Instead of getters and setters, it is more constructor based now. Also, fixed the code sample.

Comment: But how to set port at the same time?

Comment: Note this XML will not work in later releases Jetty 9 -- I am using 9.2.3. sprynter's answer works.

Comment: @BinWang I'm using `http=new ServerConnector...` then `http.setPort` and `server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{http});`

Answer (score 21):

As noted, and corrected in the Java code example above, the threadpool is now provided as a constructor argument in Jetty 9 (and later).

The corrected XML example:

```xml
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Configure the Server Thread Pool.                           -->
    <!--                                                             -->
    <!-- Consult the javadoc of o.e.j.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool   -->
    <!-- for all configuration that may be set here.                 -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Get name="ThreadPool">
        <Set name="minThreads" type="int">10</Set>
        <Set name="maxThreads" type="int">200</Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout" type="int">60000</Set>
        <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
    </Get>
    ...
```

Comment: Will this method work for Jetty HTTP Client?  Where does the file go in JAR file for an embedded client?

Comment: This is the only thing I found on the internet that works. I'm using the Jetty Maven plugin v9.2.2. Thanks!!