# Set Queue Limit via jetty.xml in Jetty 9 Maven Plugin

Tags: java, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

The thread pool in Jetty by default is implemented with an unbounded queue once the thread pool fills up. I'd like to put a limit on the size of the queue. There is a constructor for `BlockingArrayQueue` that takes a `maxCapacity` value but I can see no way to call it using jetty.xml. As of Jetty 9, there is no setter for the threadpool in `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server`, I can only get a reference to the thread pool that has already been instantiated and mutate it (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21841959/120102)). And the setter for the queue field in `QueuedThreadPool` throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`, saying to use constructor injection. But this is impossible if I can only mutate the thread pool, not set a new one on the server instance. Attempting to define the thread pool as a constructor arg yields the following warning:

2014-09-22 13:15:13.688:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Ignored arg: |    200501000|        6000|      false|

This is with the Jetty Maven Plugin v9.2.2.v20140723. Here is the configuration in my pom.xml:

```
    <configuration>
      <jettyXml>${basedir}/jetty.xml</jettyXml>
      <stopKey>x</stopKey>
      <stopPort>7999</stopPort>
      <requestLog implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
        <append>true</append>
      </requestLog>
      <webApp>
        <war>${basedir}/target/app</war>
        <contextPath>/app</contextPath>
      </webApp>
      <scanTargets>
        <scanTarget>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/</scanTarget>
      </scanTargets>
      <reload>manual</reload>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** The Server constructor is how you configure the thread pool, unfortunately, [you cannot configure the Server constructor from within jetty-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/maven/plugin/JettyServer.java#L55-L57).  That is out of scope for the jetty-maven-plugin.

---

The ThreadPool in Jetty 9 is now setup in the [Constructor of the `Server`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html#Server(org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPool)) instance.

Using XML, you can reconfigure it, it's even [documented in the jetty.xml itself](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty.xml#L45-L47).

Feel free to change it, just be aware that bound thread pools are known to cause problems if the limit is too small.

Here's a handy napkin formula.

Max Threads = (((number of cpu cores) * 4) * (connector count)) + (max concurrent requests)

In practice, most values under 400 are going to cause you problems on even mildly busy servers.  Don't take this statement as meaning 400 is a good starting point, that would be grossly improper of you, you need to test, and monitor, and keep adjusting until you find a happy value for your server.  (Don't forget to test for load spikes, and what happens when your databases fail)

Thinking that you need to set an upper bounds for performance is a form of [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Its true that the QueuedThreadPool that Jetty uses is unbound, but it also cleans itself up and removes threads from the pool over time, allowing the server to handle sudden loads and back off when the load subsides.

If its memory or other resources you are concerned about, know that the default Jetty installation runs fine on even Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) (note: Jetty 7 w/QTP), Android 4.4 (Jetty 9), and Raspberry Pi (Jetty 7 thru 9).

Lastly, how to set your accept queue size.

Configure your [`ServerConnector`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html) (usually found in the [`etc/jetty-http.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty-http.xml#L23))

```xml
<Set name="acceptQueueSize">40</Set>
```

The default value is `0`, and relates to the `backlog` parameter in the [`ServerSocketChannel.bind(SocketAddress,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html#bind(java.net.SocketAddress,%20int)) call at the lowest levels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking at the possibility of setting the queue size based on this document: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/High_Load, as well as in trying to reproduce this bug on my dev box: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=444031.

Anyway with regards to actually updating the thread pool, I had tried what jetty.xml suggests, but I get this warning:
WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Ignored arg: <Arg name="threadpool"><New id="threadpool" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool"/></Arg>

Comment: wiki.eclipse.org is for Jetty 7 and 8. not jetty 9. (as it says at the top of the wiki)

Comment: The only reason for that ignored arg, is if you have something configuring the Server before that xml has a chance to execute. (would need details of your startup / configuration / ${jetty.base} to know more).  But this is now WAY out of scope for this comment section.  Bring your question to the jetty-users mailing list.

Comment: Thanks, I'll disregard the information in the Wiki. But I do think trying to get this Server configured via jetty.xml is within the scope of this question (while the why part may not be). I've updated the question to be more specific to the Jetty Maven plugin since that's what I'm using. I added the configuration portion of the plugin...not sure what other detail there is to give you, everything else is out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks, the update answered my question. It sounds like you don't recommend setting a limit on the accept queue but it was recommended as a possible step to take in Comment 20 of https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=444031 so I am going to try it out and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

We faced a similar issue where in we wanted the Server to reject the requests if all threads are busy instead of queuing them indefinitely.

I think this is a genuine ask, following is the approach.

Since its not possible to override the default pool size or type in the Jetty Server. We wrote a custom ServerConnector, where in you can set the queue size or your executor for that matter.

```
jetty.addServerCustomizers((Server server) -> {
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue< (maxQueueSize);
    ExecutorService exceutorService =
        new ThreadPoolExecutor(minThreads, maxThreads, 1,
            TimeUnit.HOURS, queue);

    // extract host and port from existing connector...
    String host = "0.0.0.0";
    int port = 1900;
    for (Connector c : server.getConnectors()) {
        if (c instanceof ServerConnector) {
            host = ((ServerConnector) c).getHost();
            port = ((ServerConnector) c).getPort();
        }
    }


    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, exceutorService, null, null, -1, -1, new HttpConnectionFactory());
    connector.setHost(host);
    connector.setPort(port);
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });
}
```

## Cons

1) Since Jetty expects a Queued threadpool, when we tried the same it used to give random results where server startup failed in-spite of correct configurations. The behavior was not predictable.

2) Since ExecutorService does not implement Threadpool the metrics collection plugin for Jetty might not work properly.

Will keep this answer updated when we hit production.