# Increasing Jetty ThreadPool size in Karaf

Tags: rest, embedded-jetty, apache-karaf

Trying to increase the number of threads in embedded jetty running in karaf .Im changing the jetty.xml with the following properties as described in the [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534025/change-thread-pool-size-in-jetty-9) .

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">   
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
        <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
        <Set name="maxThreads">1000</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg> 
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

And also having **org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg** file in karaf ,with below properties :

```
   org.ops4j.pax.web.config.file=${karaf.home}/jetty.xml
```

so to refer the external configurations (Jetty). But Im not able to increase/decrease the default thread size of the server . So What am I missing ?

Comment: What version of Jetty?   That XML is bad, there's no such method to `.addConnector(ThreadPool)`

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt is correct. The accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534025/change-thread-pool-size-in-jetty-9 is now out of date. sprynter has an updated answer.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt : The above **jetty.xml** is generarted when i do a **features:install jetty** in karaf.

Comment: @shashantrika file a bug with karaf, that XML is not going to work.

Comment: But this won't help in the Pax-Web Context, please open an issue for this at the ops4j jira. So we can take a look at it how to pass those params to the embedded instance.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt and why should he file a bug at Karaf? Just because there is no QueuedThreadPool which can be configured through a connector. This is already obviously wrong made on the assumption to change that due to the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534025/change-thread-pool-size-in-jetty-9

Comment: The following issue takes care of setting those properties: https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXWEB-868

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest Pax-Web 4.2.0 it's possible to configure those settings via configuration admin. The following three new settings can be used:

```
org.ops4j.pax.web.server.maxThreads
org.ops4j.pax.web.server.minThreads
org.ops4j.pax.web.server.idleTimeout
```