# how to set the jetty thread pool in Google App Engine flexible environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I know how to set the thread pool in a normal jetty project: [Change thread pool size in Jetty 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534025/change-thread-pool-size-in-jetty-9)

My question is how to configure this in a App Engine flexible environment.

I looked at: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-jetty9
but it does not show a way how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not limitations for Google App Engine Flex, you’re free to create threads or processes that live outside of the request environment. You could try to take a look at this documentation, even though it's specify for [Google App Engine Standar](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime).

Let me know how it goes.